# Java Regex - mask credit card number

Tags: java, regex, string

I have the function which masks credit card numbers in String:

```
  public static String  replaceCreditCardNumber(String text){
         final String MASKCARD = "$1<MASKED>$2";
         final Pattern PATTERNCARD = 
            Pattern.compile("([0-9]{4})[0-9]{0,9}([0-9]{4})");    
         Matcher matcher = PATTERNCARD.matcher(text);
         if (matcher.find()) {
             return   matcher.replaceAll(MASKCARD);
         }
         return text;

    }
```

this function works fine in the following cases:

```
    String text = "Aaaa bbbb aaa=1234567890123456 fdfdfd=aaa";
    String expected = "Aaaa bbbb aaa=1234<MASKED>3456 fdfdfd=aaa";
    assertEquals(expected,text);//OK

    String text = "Aaaa bbbb aaa=\"1234567890123456\" fdfdfd=aaa";
    String expected = "Aaaa bbbb aaa=\"1234<MASKED>3456\" fdfdfd=aaa";
    assertEquals(expected,text);
```

However the following case fails

```
        String text = "Aaaa bbbb aaa=1gfg23fgfg4567890123456 fdfdfd=aaa";
        String expected = "Aaaa bbbb aaa=1gfg23fgfg4567890123456 fdfdfd=aaa";
        assertEquals(expected,text);
```

I'm getting

```
        aaa=1gfg23fgfg4567[<MASKED>]3456
```

What am I missing in my regex expression?

Comment: Why do you have `[0-9]{0,9}` in the middle? Isn't a credit card number always 16 digits?

Comment: You are asking for 4 digits, then up to nine digits, and another 4 digits - and thats what you have in the "failing" case. Therefore, the middle 5 digits are replaced. Do you need to have 8 digits to be masked?

Comment: @Keppli - not really - they can have 14 (Diners Club) or 15 (American Express), too. Some Visas even have 13. [Here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/creditcard.html) is a resource which includes some suggestions for credit/debit card regexes

Comment: @Vld: Ok, so `[0-9]{5,8}` might make more sense then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use word boundaries to make sure to avoid matching unwanted input:

```
final Pattern PATTERNCARD = 
        Pattern.compile("\\b([0-9]{4})[0-9]{0,9}([0-9]{4})\\b");
```

#### [Working Demo](http://regex101.com/r/zT1kI3)

Answer (score 2):

Based on examples:

```
Pattern.compile("([0-9]{4})[0-9]{8}([0-9]{4})");
```

Answer (score 1):

**I hope to serve you**

I have the following class:

```
    public class PatternCreditCard {

  // ------------------------- PATTERN DEFINE TYPE CREDIT --------------------------- //
  public static final String VISA = "^4.*";
  public static final String VISA_ELECTRON = "^(4026|417500|4508|4844|491(3|7)).*";
  public static final String MASTER_CARD = "^5[1-5].*";
  public static final String AMEX = "^3[47].*";
  public static final String DISCOVER =
      "^(6011|622(12[6-9]|1[3-9][0-9]|[2-8][0-9]{2}|9[0-1][0-9]|92[0-5]|64[4-9])|65).*";
  public static final String DINERS = "^36.*";
  public static final String DINERS_CARTE_BLANCHE = "^30[0-5].*";
  public static final String JCB = "^35(2[89]|[3-8][0-9]).*";

  // ------------------------- PATTERN SEPARATOR GROUP NUMBERS --------------------------- //
  public static final String VISA_SEPARATOR =
      "^([0-9 ]{5})([0-9 ]{5})?([0-9 ]{5})?(?:([0-9 ]{5})([0-9 ]{5})?([0-9]{5})([0-9]{4}))?$";

  public static final String MASTER_CARD_SEPARATOR =
      "^([0-9 ]{5})([0-9 ]{5})?([0-9 ]{5})?(?:([0-9 ]{5})([0-9 ]{5})?([0-9]{5})([0-9]{4}))?$";

  public static final String AMEX_SEPARATOR =
      "^([0-9 ]{5})([ ]?[0-9 ]{7})?(?:([ ]?[0-9 ]{7})([ ]?[0-9]{5}))?$";

  public static final String DISCOVER_SEPARATOR =
      "^([0-9 ]{5})([0-9 ]{5})?([0-9 ]{5})?(?:([0-9 ]{5})([0-9 ]{5})?([0-9]{5})([0-9]{4}))?$";

  // ------------------------- LENGTH PERMITTED FOR CREDIT CARD --------------------------- //
  public static final int VISA_LEN = 16;
  public static final int MASTER_CARD_LEN = 16;
  public static final int AMEX_LEN = 15;
  public static final int DISCOVER_LEN = 16;

}
```

then do a replacement to the String of the credit card number if the return value is "" (empty): means that the String complies with any group in the regular expression.

```
cardNumber.replaceAll(VISA_SEPARATOR, " ");
```